# Forcing UTF8 Format with PHP's XMLReader, DOM and SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

We have a script that parses XML feeds from user generated sources which from time to time contain improperly formated entries with special characters.

While I would normally just run utf8_encode() on the line, I'm not certain how to do this as DOM is progressively reading the file and the error is thrown as the expand command takes place.

Since simple_xml chokes on the code, subsequent lines are also off.

Here's the code.

```
$z = new XMLReader; 
$z->open($filename); $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');         
while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'product');   
while ($z->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT AND $z->name === 'product'){
$producti = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));
print_r($producti);
}
```

Errors:

> Message:  XMLReader::expand(): foo.xml:29081: parser error : Input is
>   not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0x05 0x20 0x2D 0x35
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  XMLReader::expand(): An Error
>   Occured while expanding
>
> Filename: controllers/feeds.php
>
> Line Number: 106
>
> Message:  Argument 1 passed to DOMDocument::importNode() must be an
>   instance of DOMNode, boolean given
>
> Filename:
>   controllers/feeds.php
>
> Line Number: 106

Comment: Do these documents *declare* that they're encoded in UTF-8 while they're actually not, or do you just not care what encoding they're in and *assume* they're encoded in UTF-8? Do you have a sample of a document that breaks your parser?

Comment: Most declare UTF-8, but not all. The variability of the files is unfortunately on me to deal with give the types of sources sending data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML Tidy library first to clean your string.

Also I'd better use DOMDocument instead of XMLReader.

Something like that:

```
        $tidy = new Tidy;

        $config = array(
                'drop-font-tags' => true,
                'drop-proprietary-attributes' => true,
                'hide-comments' => true,
                'indent' => true,
                'logical-emphasis' => true,
                'numeric-entities' => true,
                'output-xhtml' => true,
                'wrap' => 0
        );

        $tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');

        $tidy->cleanRepair();

        $xml = $tidy->value; // Get clear string

        $dom = new DOMDocument;

        $dom->loadXML($xml);

        ...
```

Comment: I'll take a look... Any insight into how to call it within the loop so that each xml block is filtered? The file is too large to clean in advance (huge memory usage).

Comment: No just apply Tidy on whole `$filename`. See modified answer.

Comment: Thank you. It's going to take some time for me to rebuild from XMLReader to DOM to fully test but seems to work so far.

Comment: For anyone else looking there's a very small typo as DOMDocumet should be DOMDocument